# Remove row where value is found as a substring of another row in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe below:

```
data = {'Name':['Trump', 'Donald Trump', 'Melania Trump', 'Mike Pence'], 'number':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
```

I would like to remove a row if the string in `Name` on that row is found as part of another row with a leading space, i.e. `Trump` is found in `Donald Trump` (it matches  `Trump`), and thus it remove the row with `Trump`.

What it is the most optimised way of doing this?

Expected output is rows 1, 2, 3 (i.e. only first row with 'Trump' is removed)

Comment: So expected output is row `0,3` ?

Comment: Looks like you need a O(n^2) solution, i.e for each string, check it is not a substring of any other

Answer (score 1):

I would first make a list of names to be removed, then filter the dataframe by that.

```
In [25]: import pandas as pd

In [26]: data = {'Name':['Trump', 'Donald Trump', 'Melania Trump', 'Mike Pence']
    ...: , 'number':[20, 21, 19, 18]}
    ...:

In [27]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)

In [28]: df.head()
Out[28]:
            Name  number
0          Trump      20
1   Donald Trump      21
2  Melania Trump      19
3     Mike Pence      18

In [29]: names_to_remove = [name for name in df.Name if any([name in _str.split(
    ...: ' ') for _str in df.Name])]


In [30]: names_to_remove
Out[30]: ['Trump']

In [31]: df = df[~df.Name.isin(names_to_remove)]

In [32]: df
Out[32]:
            Name  number
1   Donald Trump      21
2  Melania Trump      19
3     Mike Pence      18
```